# Protractor : how to compare the text content of the same web element before and after clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I would like to test a filtering function in my angularJS app.
In fact when I click on the filter the number of search results displayed on the page should decrease
Here is is my code so far :

```
    element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then (function(text){console.log(text); })
    element(by.repeater('term in facets.uproctype').row(0)).click ()
    element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then (function(text){console.log(text); })
```

And here is my console log :

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
6209
6195
....
```

I don't know how can I compare theses two values in an expect line as I can't use them inside their function.
Any help?

Thanks
Zied

Comment: Did you try to assign to variables in the `then`: `oldValue = text` and `newValue = text` in the second one?

Comment: Yes i did but it won't work as I can't access oldValue and newValue outside the functions whereas i wouls like to compare theses values later in an expect line.

Comment: Even if you declare them above in the `decribe` or the `it`, and assign them in the `then`?

Comment: Yes it will return undefined as value, I guess because it's asynchronous. Not sure as I am quite new to JS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you would have to nest your then functions to ensure the original value is available.

```
element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then( function(original_text) {

  element(by.repeater('term in facets.uproctype').row(0)).click ();

  element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then( function(new_text){
    expect(original_text).not.toBe(new_text);
  });

});
```

This link also might be helpful. 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to schedule the comparison at the protractor control flow so it will be executed after all values are available.

```
var oldValue,newValue;
element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then(function(text){oldValue=text})
element(by.repeater('term in facets.uproctype').row(0)).click()
element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText().then(function(text){newValue=text})

protractor.promise.controlFlow()
  .execute(function(){return protractor.promise.fulfilled()},'wait for control flow')
    .then(function(){
      expect(oldValue).not.toEqual(newValue);
    });
```

There is a nice explanation of flow.execute() in this [blog post](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you can just compare the results of `.getText()` from different points using `expect`

```
var text1 = element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText();
element(by.repeater('term in facets.uproctype').row(0)).click();
var text2 = element(by.id('foundNumber')).getText();
expect(text1).not.toBe(text2);
```

`expect` handles unwrapping of the promises passed to it and actually compares resolved values.